# How to create an event in Office 365 with team meeting url using client credentials

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

During the current crisis in Europe we want to enable team meetings for a lot of events we create in Office 365.

We use the [Create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint to create appointments in the users calendars.
For authentication we use an authorized Client application with client credentials, so for permissions we always have to look in **Application** column for the required permissions.

It their a way to tell this endpoint to also generate the `onlineMeetingUrl`?

I found out that there is also an [Create Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint, but that has a). no support for Applications and b). that would result in 2 calls per event to create (one to create the online meeting and a second to create the event with the meeting).

Comment: You can use the Create Online Meeting endpoint it will give you joinWebUrl through which participants can join, but this will not be shown up in calendar as an event.

Comment: This isn't any help. The **Create Online Meeting** endpoint explicitly states that application permissions aren't supported (as stated in the original question)

Comment: Could you please give the delegated permissions for this API?

Comment: I cannot give delegated permissions, since there isn't a user logged-in to the application. The beta endpoint states **Application permissions** but they will be **removed tomorrow** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Pleas take a look at [Create Event with Online Meeting provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting)

Comment: Please take a look for detailed answer : [Create Event with joinWebUrl](https://stackoverflow.microsoft.com/questions/193281?noredirect=1#comment174173_193281)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft changed the api in the past months. If you want to create an event with an online meeting you just need to set `isOnlineMeeting` to `true` when creating or updating the event. This will trigger the creation of the online meeting with the same details as the calendar event (times, subject, participants).

This is also documented here [Create event with online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting).

Hope it can also help others.